# unicode characters issues in dataset using AspenTech.SQLplus

Tags: c#, database, sqlplus, aspen

I have AspenTech database and in my database i am storing unicode charater everything is working perfect

but when i am calling data using below code and not getting unicode char date right way in my data set

```
objDataSet = New DataSet("Result")
        objConn = New SQLplusConnection(strConnectionString)
        objCom = New SQLplusCommand
        objCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim objDataAdapter As New SQLplusDataAdapter(objCom)

        objCom.Connection = objConn
        objConn.Open()
        objSB.Append("sql statment ")
objCom.CommandText = objSB.ToString

            objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet)
```

i am using AspenTech.SQLplus and c# 
also i have added unicode html tag in my html page

Answer (score 1):

AspenTech.SQLplus.DataProvider doesn't support Unicode chars (see Aspentech support).
You will have to use the .Net ODBC : System.Data.Odbc